# I can't open my class just find a BuildConfig file

Tags: java, android-studio

For unknown reason a java file in an android studio project 
has a sub arrow to BuildConfig class from an other package of an other project

```
/**
 * Automatically generated file. DO NOT MODIFY
 */
package alsayed.aly.maintenanceplaner;

public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "alsayed.aly.maintenanceplaner";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
}
```

I tried to revert it but it is not working as the file just created now.

Answer (score 0):

At build time, Gradle generates the BuildConfig class so your app code can inspect information about the current build.

You can also add custom fields to the BuildConfig class from your Gradle build configuration file using the buildConfigField() method and access those values in your app's runtime code. Likewise, you can add app resource values with resValue().

```
 android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      // These values are defined only for the release build, which
      // is typically used for full builds and continuous builds.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${minutesSinceEpoch}\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "${minutesSinceEpoch}")
      ...
    }
    debug {
      // Use static values for incremental builds to ensure that
      // resource files and BuildConfig aren't rebuilt with each run.
      // If they were dynamic, they would prevent certain benefits of
      // Instant Run as well as Gradle UP-TO-DATE checks.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "0")
    }
  }
}
```

In your app code, you can access the properties as follows:

```
Log.i(TAG, BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME);
Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.build_time));
```